# L'Hopital Rule: For what value(s) of $p$, if any, is this limit equal to $1$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, analysis, transcendental-functions

For what value(s) of $p$, if any, do we have
$$
\lim_{x \to p} \frac{ p^x - x^p }{ x^x - p^p } = 1?
$$

My Attempt:

> Since $0^0$ is indeterminate, we must have $p \neq 0$.

> If we put $x = p$ into $\frac{ p^x - x^p }{ x^x - p^p }$, we find that
> $$
> \frac{ p^x - x^p }{ x^x - p^p }  = \frac{ p^p - p^p }{ p^p - p^p } = \frac{0}{0}.
> $$
> Thus we have the $\frac{0}{0}$ form. So, provided that the indicated limits exist, we have
> $$
> \begin{align}
> \lim_{x \to p} \frac{ p^x - x^p }{ x^x - p^p } &= \lim_{x \to p} \frac{ \frac{d}{dx} \left( p^x - x^p  \right) }{ \frac{d}{dx} \left( x^x - p^p \right) } \\ 
> &= \lim_{x \to p} \frac{ p^x \ln p - p x^{p-1} }{ x^x (1 + \ln x)  } \tag{1} \\
> &= \frac{ p^p ( \ln p - 1 ) }{ p^p ( \ln p + 1) } \\ & \qquad \qquad \mbox{ [ provided that $p \neq e^{-1}$] } \\
> &= \frac{ \ln p - 1}{ \ln p + 1}. 
> \end{align}
> $$
> However, if
> $$
> \frac{ \ln p - 1}{ \ln p + 1} = 1, 
> $$
> then we also have
> $$
> \ln p - 1 = \ln p + 1, 
> $$
> and hence $-1 = 1$, which is impossible.

> So let us suppose that $p = e^{-1}$. Then using (1) above, we have
> $$
> \begin{align}
> \lim_{x \to e^{-1} } \frac{ (1/e)^x - x^{1/e} }{ x^x  - e^{-1/e} } &= \lim_{x \to e^{-1} } \frac{ e^{-x} (-1) - e^{-1} x^{ 1/e - 1}  }{ x^x (1 + \ln x)   } \\ 
> &= \frac{ -e^{-1/e} - e^{-1} \left( e^{-1} \right)^{ 1/e - 1}  }{ (1/e)^{1/e} \left(1 + \ln e^{-1} \right) } \\
> &= \frac{ -2 e^{-1/e} }{ 0 } \\
> &= -\infty.
> \end{align} 
> $$

> Hence there is no value of $p$ for which the indicated limit equals $1$.

Is this solution correct? If not, then where have I erred?

How to solve this problem with full detail and rigor typical of mathematical analysis arguments?

Comment: Looks correct, but how do you know that the limit for $e^{-1}$ is equal $+\infty,$ I mean the $+$ sign.  Actaully you do not need to repeat calculations for $p=e^{-1}.$ Just apply the previous calculations for the reciprocal of the function.

Comment: Writing things like $\lim _{x\to 0} \frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{0}$ is considered bad style. Plus the second equality for the case $p=1/e$ requires some care. Technically speaking, you already assume the limit exists, but I don't at least immediately see why that would be.

Comment: I do not understand why the OP feels the need to ask this fairly simple highschool math question, whereas his high reputation (25.8k) indicates that he is an expert !?

Comment: Sanity checking himself? It's not a low effort post, why the backlash? Since when did reputation become an infallible indicator of expertise? @M.Wind